# How can i have a custom post type with more slugs for each post?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, urls, paths

I have a post type /city/ ..
lets say i create a city called toronto with the slug toronto-canada.

now i have /city/toronto-canada/

is there a way i can have more paths for each post in the custom post type added dynamically?

for example when i make the toronto post there should be a path that is:
/city/toronto-canada/stores
and
/city/toronto-canada/things-to-do

pretty much just a defined url for each post /city/toronto-canada/whatever

```
// City Post Type & Taxonomy
function create_city_category_hierarchical_taxonomy() {
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Categories' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Categories' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Category' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Category' ),
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Category' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Category' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Category Name' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Categories' ),
  );
  register_taxonomy('city_category',null, array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'cities'),
  ));
}
function city_post_type() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Cities', 'post type general name' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'City', 'post type singular name' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New City' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit City' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New City' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All Cities' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Cities' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Cities' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No City found' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Cities found in the Trash' ),
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => 'Cities'
  );

  $args = array(
    'labels'        => $labels,
    'description'   => 'Holds xxx Cities',
    'public'        => true,
    'menu_position' => 99999,
    'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes','comments' ),
    'taxonomies'    => array('city_category'),
    'has_archive'   => true,
    'has_parent'    => true,
    'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-building',
    'hierarchical'  => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'city'),
  );
  register_post_type( 'city', $args );
  flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_city_category_hierarchical_taxonomy', 0 );
add_action( 'init', 'city_post_type' );
```

Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with a custom rewrite.
I am doing the same for a custom post type, in my case profile.

So my URL = `domain.com/profile/some-custom-slug`.
Dynamically I create `/meet-me` behind it, so it becomes `domain.com/profile/some-custom-slug/meet-me`.

The real address of the contact page is `domain.com/profile/some-custom-slug/?meet=true` (or something else unique).

```
function wpse343933_todo() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'city/([^/]*)/(things-to-do)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=city&name=$matches[1]&subpage=$matches[2]', 'top' );
}
add_filter( 'init', 'wpse343933_todo', 1, 3 );
```

The code should be placed in *functions.php*.

Now we've only made the address 'reachable', but it shows the singular post.

In your *singular.php* you need to add an `if` statement to 'catch' this new variable.

The code for this is real easy:

```
if ( true == get_query_var( 'meet' ) {
    // output content for this particular 'sub page'
} else {
    // output content for the 'normal post'
}
```

I think this should do the trick.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that the new sub page will not be crawled from google? is there a way to make a template for the sub page that google would be able to crawl instead?

Comment: Or would google crawl both the city/single/ and city/single/things-to-do seperately?

Comment: I think that, if you link to it from a page, Google will notice the link and crawl it, but I am not 100% sure.